# HTML for email/Outlook, how to get an image to crop (overflow:hidden) based on height of text

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am working on converting a PSD email design into and HTML email template. I am aware that working on HTML for email is like web design in the 90's. Have warned the client that this may not be possible, and I've been trying a number of hacks and so far nothing I've tried has worked.

Here is the problem: the email design has a border running down each side of the body of the email. The border is not recreatable using html since it is a fancy border, with some drop shadow and embossing.

Since it runs the vertical length of the email, and each email will have a different vertical length depending on the amount of text, I was hoping there would be an email safe way to maybe use one large image that would be revealed as more text made it necessary.

With regular web design, I would use background-image and overflow:hidden. Those do not work with the latest version of Outlook however. I've tried a number of other tricks, but can't seem to get the desired result.

Does anyone have any suggestions or do I go back to the client and tell them this is just not possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! E-mails can use inline CSS, so there's a large chance you can get such a design working. However, it's hard to come up with such a design without the sample E-mail. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)

Comment: I encountered something similar some time ago. I ended up coding each of the pixel as a column with colors extracted from photoshop. since it was colors i didnt have to worry about the email height as the columns kept increasing and decreasing depending on the content.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice for HTML emails is to keep it simple, and when designing them to avoid things like fancy backgrounds and borders. But we all know sometimes designers have other ideas and we have to work with what we've got.

The next best thing is progressive enhancement - use the fancy background border where it works, and have an acceptable fallback where it doesn't.

Finally, I'm not sure what you have tried, but there's always *Stig's [Bulletproof Email Background Images](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/06/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/)* by Campaign Monitor.

Hopefully that gives you some ideas for how to continue.